# How to write a script to find databases that are used in SQL server database objects like storedproc and views?

Tags: sql, database, object

One of our databases (Database A) in SQL server 2012 is retiring soon. I am in a process to analyze all Views and StoredProcs in Database B that uses Database A as a data source. How do I write a query to retrieve this information. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following to get objects and their dependencies in SQL Server 2008:

```
select *
from (select referenced_database_name, o.name as ViewName, ed.referenced_entity_name as TableName
      from sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed join
           sys.objects o
           on ed.referencing_id = o.object_id
      where referenced_database_name is not null
     ) vdep
```

You can add a filter to filter out databases you are or are not interested in:

```
where referenced_database_name = 'A'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks so much for the suggestion. It works great! WOuld it be possible to break down objects into views, storedprocs and tables so that I get information in separate columns. Thanks again

Comment: @poshan . . . The infromation you want is in `sys.objects`.  You can just add `type` and `type_desc` to the subquery.  (It is a subquery because when I use it, I'm often joining to other lists.)

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That really helped. Next, when I tried joining sys.columns on object_ID to know what columns are used in those objects, I was able to get all the columns used in views but got NULL when it is storedProc. Any thoughts on that issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way would be to just query the procedure text

```
select p.name 
from sys.procedures p 
    inner join sys.syscomments c ON (p.object_id = c.id)
where c.text like '%database.%' or c.text like '%[database].%'
```

The same query can be done on `sys.views` as well. You may or may not get very good results depending on the database name and the naive algorithm I have given you.

I'm not sure if sp_depends works on databases or not, but I'm guessing there's dependencies you could query for the database as well, I just don't know how.

Comment: Thanks Darren for the tip. I appreciate it.